# Yarn: Procedure for redeploying JavaScript dependencies to Production Server (usage of `yarn.lock` file)

Tags: javascript, git, version-control, yarnpkg

I've read the documentation on Yarn, and I know the `lock` file is supposed to be committed to VC.  See [this](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/lockfiles-for-all/) and which explains at a high-level why the lock file is necessary, and [this](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm) which lists a bunch of commands without much explanation of what they actually do!

I've also read a lot of questions on StackOverflow which asks about whether the `lock` file should be committed to VC.

However, all the documentation and SO threads seems to overlook the detail that I want to know, which is the following;  What is the correct procedure (the correct bunch of commands to run) for:

1. Updating the `yarn.lock` file when I need to (i.e. in the development environment where I want to pull the latest minor versions and update the `lock` file to reflect this)
2. For keeping my lock file in sync with other developers to ensure that they are developing/testing from the exact same dependency versions, and
3. For updating/re-synching the `node_modules` directory on the production server (i.e. to ensure that the production server isn't running on a different/breaking version of dependent packages)

I ask partly because in the past while doing a `git pull` on the server, I've faced messages telling me that the `yarn.lock` file has been updated independently of the development/VC process.  As far as I'm concerned, this should never be allowed to happen.

Comment: When specifying packages in the package.json file for when adding packages, it's always a good idea to specify the `exact version` of the package to install. This is the mechanism to help you maintain correct packages across systems. ie: `yarn add my-package@1.0.1` and be more diligent when installing newer versions of the package to ensure compatibility with other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Honestly, this is a matter of opinion/preference. I have seen a few strategies:

   - Using `yarn upgrade`
   - Manually bumping the version in `package.json` before running `yarn`
2. Like Fabien mentioned: use `yarn check`
3. You can use yarn offline mirrors where you commit caches of your npm packages into version control. (See [this](https://medium.com/@chrishouse/speed-up-ci-builds-with-npm-offline-cache-aa72a2bb63c5) medium article)

   Plus there are lots of upsides when using `yarn --offline`:

   - Builds are faster because you don't have to fetch packages from the npm registry.
   - Your builds will fail if you do not have the right dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

the following information are based on what we use daily at Orange, this may be not the single truth.

1 ) Updating `yarn.lock`

```
yarn upgrade [package | package@tag | package@version | @scope/]... [--ignore-engines] [--pattern]
```

This command updates dependencies to their latest version based on the version range specified in the `package.json` file. The `yarn.lock` file will be recreated as well.

source : https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade

2) Dependency between developers

What i suggest you to do is to create a script that will check the current 'recomended' version to have with the help of:

`yarn check`

Verifies that versions of the package dependencies in the current project’s `package.json` match those in yarn’s lock file.

source : https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check

3) Updating server production

The same as 2 ) using a git hook script, should help you to `yarn check` if the `package.json` version are correct if not launch a `yarn update`.